# How to adjust the div as below image?

Tags: php, html, css

I want adjust my div like this,

```
     <------------------header--------------------->  
========================================================
tree structure          table div
        ==         
        ==     =
        ==     ===========================================
        ==     = graph div     = drop down div
        ==
        ==                     =
                               =             
  =========================================================
  footer
```

[image]

My code is,

```
<?php
include("Config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
echo"<div style=\"width: 100%; height:7%; background-color: green; color: white; id=header;\">";
echo"</div>";   
echo"<div style=\"width:20%; height:86%;color: white; background-color:pink;class=page-container;\">";  
<---------some codes---------------->

                        echo"</div>";//tree div ends

                        echo"<div style=\"width:80%; height:38%; background-color: skyblue; color:white;float:left;\">
                right div1";echo"</div>";

                        echo"<div style=\"width: 20%; height:50%; background-color: lightblue; color:white;float:left;\">
                right div2";echo"</div>";

                        echo"<div style=\"width:300px; height:53%; background-color:orange; color: white; float:left;\">
                right div3";echo"</div>";

                echo"<div style=\"width: 1600px; height:5%; background-color: green; color: white; float:left; left;\">
                footer div";echo"</div>";
}//inside if ends
?>
```

can any one help me I am struggling  a lot to do this.

Comment: Make your life easy and use bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple solution with flex with the use of external CSS as your shouldn't write all the styles as inline.

*I used only HTML in order to show the result but i think you can easily `echo` it wth PHP later.*

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

header,
footer {
  min-height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.left {
  flex: 2;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
}

.bottom>div {
  flex: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, black);
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="left">
    <div class="top">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: @Vidya why you removed the corrected mark ? is there any issue with the solution ... if yes let me know, i will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox you could do it like this. However, I would recommend splitting out the CSS from the PHP file.

```
<?php
include("Config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {

echo '<style type="text/css">
                body {
                    margin: 0;
                }

                .header, .footer {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 3rem;
                    background: green;
                }

                .content-wrapper {
                    height: calc(100vh - 6rem);
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: nowrap;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    justify-content: space-evenly;
                }

                .left-col {
                    width: 20%;
                    background: pink;
                    height: 100%;
                }

                .right-col {
                    width: 80%;
                    height: 100%;
                    display: flex;
                    flex-wrap: wrap;
                }

                .cell {
                    background: #ccc; 
                }

                .dark-blue {
                    width: 100%;
                    flex-grow: 1;
                    background: steelblue;
                }

                .light-blue {
                    width: 70%;
                    background: aqua;
                }

                .orange {
                    width: 30%;
                    background: orange;
                }
            </style>';

echo    '<div class="header">Header</div>
                    <div class="content-wrapper">
                        <div class="left-col">Pink</div>
                        <div class="right-col">
                        <div class="cell dark-blue">Dark blue</div>
                        <div class="cell light-blue">Light blue</div>
                        <div class="cell orange">Orange</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">Footer</div>';

}
}
?>
```